# Dual boot windows 10 crashing

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10.I have lenovo g50 series 64 bit laptop. The BIOS mode is legacy supported. The grub didn't show windows 10 after installing Ubuntu so I updated grub.After that it did show windows 10 but Windows 10 began to crash sometimes on booting. I even tried boot repair but windows 10 still crashes frequently on booting. I don't know what's wrong with its booting. It works fine if it gets booted properly.I cant find anything on internet that is helpful.The crashed window is black screen with small horizontal lines . Please help!

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. And Windows cannot be hibernated, nor the NTFS partition needing chkdsk. And Ubuntu must be installed in UEFI boot mode to be able to boot Windows in UEFI boot mode. You may need to directly boot Windows and make sure fast start up (hibernation) is off. You can directly boot from UEFI boot menu often f10 or f12 (check manual). http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: I did turn off the fast reboot option long ago